# list view Selected item Changes when scrolled out of view

Tags: java, android

I have a list view which is populated with custom rows. each row has some data and a circle image which turns green on click of it . i basically wanted to replicate a "read" status as in "this msg is read if circle image  turns green". i have used a base adapter to show the view on the screen. i have managed to  change the color to green.

```
if(messagealertAdapterObject.status!=null && 
   messagealertAdapterObject.equals("read")) {
    select.setImageResource(R.drawable.greencircle);
}else{
    select.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray);
}
```

But my problem is that once the color has been changed to green after selecting the particular row if I scroll the list, as the selected image goes out of the view it comes back to the "unread" status As in the color no longer stays green once it has gone out of view.

Is there some method where I could make the color stay green even when the "circle" goes out of the view?

Comment: Hello Pradeep, You should do a little re-search before putting the question up, look for similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is concerning the ListView behavior of recycling its views when scrolling. What you need to do is to extend your list adapter and override *getView* method to handle color assignment on selected item.

For more info, read [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) and [this](http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/the-nuance-of-android-listview-recycling-for-n00bs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have understand your problem.
```

You need to maintain a boolean arraylist and need to save all of your states in that one.Whenever you scroll your listview it recreates its views so you need to save the state of views. I am giving an example I think it will help your.

```
//maintain a listview in your custom adapter:

private ArrayList<Boolean> itemRead      = null;

//initialize it in your custom adapter constructor:

   for (int i=0; i < no_of_elements.size(); i++)
   {
        itemRead.add(i, false);
   }
```

In your getView write this code:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
     //WRITE YOUR CODE

     if (itemRead.get(position) == true)
     {
         //SET YOUR ALREADY READ IMAGE
     } else {
        // SET UNREAD IMAGE
     }
}
```

Whenever a person read a row just save your status in itemRead.add(row_position, true)

this will solve your problem because each time whenever it recreate your view it takes the save status and set your image according to that one. 
Hope it will work..